# Which action gives reputation points?

Tags: hacker-experience

In the last days my reputation has skyrocketed, I'm wondering what are all the actions rewarding reputation points. I already know about missions, but what about other actions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty much every action you do against another player, server or an NPC gives you reputation points. Hacking their root access, installing and running a virus, etc are all actions that give you points.

It is a bit hard to say exactly how many points you get by actions because it depends on the security level of your oponent and on the action you are doing.

A good example is with DDOS attacks. When you DDOS someone, you dont only get reputation points for yourself, but if you are in a clan, you clan also wins some power points which work in the same way.